# Dask - too many open files (sockets)

Tags: python, websocket, dask, dask-distributed

I am facing too many open files issue w.r.t Tornado and Dask distributed.

To simulate what I am facing, Following is the code:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures._base import CancelledError
from distributed import Client, as_completed
import dask
import numpy as np

client_url = 'x.x.x.x:port' # replace with ur dask distributed cluster. I started with 1 process and 16 threads
client = Client(client_url)

cols = ['id', 'name', 'x',  'y'] * 1000
df = dask.datasets.timeseries()

def some_py_fn(col_name):
    # simulating pure python operation
    time.sleep(2)
    np.correlate([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5]) #just for the sake of it
    return df[col_name].count().compute()

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    futures = client.map(some_py_fn, cols)
    for batch in as_completed(futures, with_results=True, raise_errors=False).batches():
        for _, result in batch:
            if isinstance(result, CancelledError):
                raise CancelledError()
            count = result
            del result
del df

client.close()
```

**What happens:**

Dask keeps opening new files which includes sockets. In this case, for me system started with roughly 5k open files to 18071 at the end of operation of which 1096 are sockets.

With complex operations one after the other, this just explodes. I am trying hard to simulate the same here. Even though the no.of open files here are relatively small, the issue I am facing is open files of the order of - `3878443`. So, making unlimited open files is really not the solution.

Also, a lot of what dask opens is `socket` and it doesn't close after run. It is hard to predict when it opens a new socket, but roughly 40% of the above number were sockets. Dask also opens same library file multiple times. Here is a sample from the above small run.

```
dask-sche 18342             ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-sche 18342 18361       ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-sche 18342 18501       ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-sche 18342 18502       ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-work 18366             ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-work 18366 18383       ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-work 18366 18385       ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
dask-work 18366 18404       ec2-user  mem       REG              259,3   1359260   51824178 /home/ec2-user/kenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/common.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

These open files keep increasing. Let me know how to mitigate the socket connections and the same files being repeatedly opening.

**Env:**

```
Tornado - 5.1.1
distributed - 2.9.3
dask - 2.9.2
```

Comment: There have been some issues around too many open sockets.  i recommend reading through the following:
- https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/faq.html#too-many-open-file-descriptors
- https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1941
- https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/2303

Comment: I have seen the above. Did not help much.

Comment: @spiralarchitect _I have seen the above. Did not help much._ Can you be more specific?

Comment: @AMC : The 1st link talks about increasing ulimit, which I have done already and doesn't help. 2nd and 3rd are merged PRs more than a year back. I am using latest and still getting the issue.

Comment: @spiralarchitect having many open files is an inherent consequence of how dask is built. It is not an 'issue' that can be 'fixed'. You just need to make sure that the OS is not limiting the number of open files.